# Using p4Python in Maya, but after file checkout, Maya loses file name and path

Tags: maya, maya-api, p4python

I have a tool that integrates some of the basic functions of perforce into maya. It worked fine in Maya2018/python2. I modified it for maya2023/python3, but I only had to change the print statements. Now when an artist checks out a file using the tool in maya2023, the file gets checked out, but maya now loses the file name and path and I'm told the local file disappears and the user has to manually save with the correct name and path. I have been troubleshooting for a while but no luck so far. We are using two different perforce workspaces for maya2018 and maya2023.

Comment: I think we found the issue. It appears that some errors are occurring when these new files are opened in maya. That is preventing maya from setting the current scene name which is causing the issue.